# How to do Input validation for Spring Boot Webflux Restful API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, bean-validation

I have the following rest controller:

```
@PostMapping()
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun createCase(@RequestBody @Valid caseRequest: CaseRequestDto     
): Mono<CaseResponseDto> {
    return caseService.createCase(caseRequest, caseType)
}
```

I have added @Valid annotation to validate my input data fields. A WebExchangeBindException is supposed to be raised if the binding fails, but this is not the exception my code is triggering, so I can not retrieve the name of the fields that failed when binding.

The exception being triggered is ServerWebInputException and that type of exception does not have ex.getBindingResult() method available to retrieve the filed errors.
Any idea why WebExchangeBindException is not the exception triggered here?

I have defined a global exception handler to catch the exception, as follows:

```
 @ExceptionHandler(WebExchangeBindException::class)
fun handleWebExchangeBindException(e: WebExchangeBindException): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> {
    
    //I WANT TO USE getBindingResult TO  READ FIELD ERRORS
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();

    ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(error -> 
    errors.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
   }
  ......
}


//This is the handler and the exception triggered when the validation fails
@ExceptionHandler(ServerWebInputException::class)
fun handleServerWebInputException(e: ServerWebInputException): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> { 
    val response = errorResponse.buildErrorResponse(MessageConstants.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMS.message, "Failed to validate input parameters")
    return ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(response, badRequest)
}
```

The Request Object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data class CaseRequestDto(
    @NotNull
    val reason: String,
    val applicationDate: LocalDateTime
}
```

Comment: Do you have `@Validated` on top of your controller class?

Comment: I think @ Validated has another purpose, to support  group validation, this is not my case here. Do you have an example that uses @Validated for a similar scenario I have depicted here. Thanks.